# Showing the correct number of questions

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

I am using Math Overflow, and I have a large set of ignored tags not to see questions in areas I know nothing about. When I list 'unanswered questions', instead of displaying, say, 50 questions, it displays 4 or 5, due to my ignored tags (there is now a message saying that it is why).

So I infer that the algorithm to show unanswered questions (for example) is:

1. Find unanswered questions
2. Sort them in stacks of 50
3. Apply filters.

If the algorithm was instead

1. Find unanswered questions
2. Apply filters.
3. Sort them in stacks of 50

Then the correct number of questions would show up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the questions with a class of `tagged-ignored-hidden` , are set to `display: none` to all the questions you've ignored via CSS styling.

All the questions with a class of `tagged-interesting` are set to highlight the questions that you have favorited.

So 50 questions are loaded for each page you go to. It's just that it's much more efficient to just hide the questions in your ignored tags with CSS , then run yours and everyone elses tags through the database, and then only load the questions you don't have ignored.

Although you have a good idea, it is just not an efficient way of running a large database and website.

[image]

Comment: Ok. I guess an easy alternative fix could be to offer the option of displaying 500 questions for example...